# PHP Composer is not adding namespace to autoload_psr4

Tags: php, composer-php

(Before I begin, I have seen the two identical questions, both set the repository type to "package" which is NOT my issue here.)

I have created my first composer packages and am trying to include them in another project. However, the autoload settings I have created are not being added to the appropriate autoload file.

Here is the dependencies composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "company/authentication",
    "description": "User authentication",
    "require": {},
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.5.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Company\\Authentication\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the parent composer.json where I am including the above file:

```
{
  "config": {
    "vendor-dir": "_framework/vendor",
    "secure-http": false
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "composer.<REDACTED>.com"
    }
  ],
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.5.*",
    "phpunit/dbunit": ">=1.2",
    "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": ">=1.2"
  },
  "require": {
    "company/authentication": "1.0.*"
  }
}
```

And finally, this is the autogenerated autoload_psr4 file:

```
// autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname(dirname($vendorDir));

return array(
    'Symfony\\Component\\Yaml\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/yaml'),
    'Doctrine\\Instantiator\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/instantiator/src/Doctrine/Instantiator'),
);
```

And as it is asked below, I am not using Satis, instead I hand created a basic repository. This is my packages.json file for my repository:

```
{
    "packages": {
        "company/authentication": {
            "1.0.0": {
                "name": "company/authentication",
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://composer.company.com/repo/authentication-1.0.0.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                }
            }
        },
etc...
```

And here is my composer.lock file:

```
{
    "_readme": [
        "This file locks the dependencies of your project to a known state",
        "Read more about it at https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file",
        "This file is @generated automatically"
    ],
    "hash": "f67a284cbfcb2cf6ae3765266015710b",
    "content-hash": "57c9067e1b3a3bb7fef45eeabb928ffd",
    "packages": [
        {
            "name": "company/authentication",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "http://composer.company.com/repo/authentication-1.0.0.zip",
                "reference": null,
                "shasum": null
            },
            "type": "library"
        }
    ],
    "packages-dev": [],
    "aliases": [],
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "stability-flags": [],
    "prefer-stable": false,
    "prefer-lowest": false,
    "platform": [],
    "platform-dev": []
}
```

Comment: can we see your `satis.json`?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for looking. I found the issue was that the dependencies and autoload settings need to be in the composer.json file of the library and in the packages.json file on the repository server. It seems that the composer.json file contents of imported dependencies are ignored by composer.

This completely confuses me - why does composer look at the server meta information to know what the dependencies are, instead of the composer.json file that is embedded with the code?

Comment: Thanks for this, too weird composer doesn't take the information that belongs to the package itself, I was driving crazy

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to update your packages info. You can do that, as the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md) suggest, with:

```
php bin/satis build <configuration file> <build dir>
```

Example:

```
php bin/satis build satis.json web/
```

You should do this every time you change something of yours `composer.json` files.

Comment: I am not using Satis, I hand created the repository, and composer seems to be copying everything as expected except for the autoloader stuff. I added the configuration file of my repository to the question.

Comment: can you delete the composer's cache folder with `composer clear-cache` and run `composer install` again?

Comment: I have done that, same result. I've actually been manually deleting the cache as well - clear-cache doesn't seem to fully delete the files.

Comment: if you download `http://composer.company.com/repo/authentication-1.0.0.zip` manually, the `composer.json` inside is the same that you posted above with the `autoload` directive?

Comment: It is. And when I look at the code that got copied into my vendor directory, that is the same as well.

Comment: which composer's version are you using? can we see your `composer.lock` file?

Comment: I am using composer Composer version 1.0-dev (40c14709f79f9d7ea35ac969cfbd7f41beb525bb) 2016-04-05 12:27:16 - seeing that I updated to 1.1.1 and cleared the cache and retried, same result.

Comment: you require also a `company/utility` package, but it isn't present in your  `composer.lock`. why? when you've changed `composer.json` did you run `composer update`?

Comment: Oh, actually company/utility is missing because I removed that dependency right before I generated the lock file the last time - trying to narrow down issues by reducing what I am trying to include. The only dependency now is company/authentication. I updated the other files above accordingly

Comment: can you try to change the version in `packages.json` from `1.0.0` to `1.0.1`, then run `composer update`?

Comment: That change just changed the version number in the composer.lock file. It removed the old and installed the code with the new version number, still no change to the autoload_psr4 though. Also, if I do composer.install in the package itself, it will add the namespace entry.

Comment: To give some extra information, I have realized that composer seems to be ignoring everything in the composer.json file, because when I add a dependency to my package's composer.json it is not included.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I have found the issue, a typo in the packages file on the server. This has taught me that composer uses the server meta information instead of the composer.json that is downloaded with the code. And all I can think about that is... why?